# AWS instances type for RPI

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2, raspbian

I have my docker image for microservice-x build on rpi

My dockerfile looks as below

```
FROM raspbian/stretch


....
```

This image runs on RPi .However if I wish to launch the docker image on AWS instance which  Amazon Machine Image (AMI) type should I use ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forgot to notice that Ubuntu server 16.04 AMI type supports both X86 and ARM architectures[image]

Answer (score 1):

For AMI I will recommend using AWS ECS docker optimized AMI (AMR).

**Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI (ARM)**

> Amazon EC2 Container Service makes it easy to manage containers at
>   scale by providing a centralized service that includes programmatic
>   access to the complete state of the containers and Amazon EC2
>   instances in the cluster, schedules containers in the proper location,
>   and uses familiar Amazon EC2 features like security groups, Amazon EBS
>   volumes, and IAM roles.

[image]

[Amazon ECS-Optimized Amazon Linux 2 AMI (ARM)](https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/B07KWFRJV3?ref=cns_srchrow)

For instance You can use [Amazon EC2 A1 instances.](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/a1/)

> Amazon EC2 A1 instances deliver significant cost savings for scale-out
>   and Arm-based applications such as web servers, containerized
>   microservices, caching fleets, and distributed data stores that are
>   supported by the extensive Arm ecosystem. A1 instances are the first
>   EC2 instances powered by AWS Graviton Processors that feature 64-bit
>   Arm Neoverse cores and custom silicon designed by AWS.

You can find more in this article

> Docker & ARM demonstrated the integration of ARM capabilities into
>   Docker Desktop Community for the first time. Docker & ARM unveiled
>   go-to-market strategy to accelerate Cloud, Edge & IoT Development.
>   These two companies have planned to streamline the app development
>   tools for cloud, edge, and internet of things environments built on
>   ARM platform. The tools include AWS EC2 A1 instances based on AWS’
>   Graviton Processors (which feature 64-bit Arm Neoverse cores). Docker
>   in collaboration with ARM will make new Docker-based solutions
>   available to the Arm ecosystem as an extension of Arm’s
>   server-tailored Neoverse platform, which they say will let developers
>   more easily leverage containers — both remote and on-premises which is
>   going to be pretty cool.

[building-arm-based-docker-images-on-docker-desktop-made-possible-using-buildx](https://collabnix.com/building-arm-based-docker-images-on-docker-desktop-made-possible-using-buildx/)

[amazon-ec2-systems-manager-adds-raspbian-os-and-raspberry-pi-support](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2017/09/amazon-ec2-systems-manager-adds-raspbian-os-and-raspberry-pi-support/)

Comment: Main question was about AMI, not instance type.